# CPU usage increases in time

Tags: java, android, cpu, cpu-usage

I am making game (asteroids, ship destroys asteroids by bullets) and I have a problem: 
 
If I spawn **50 asteroids at start**, cpu usage is about **2-3%**. Its OK. 
But if I spawn **5 asteroids** and then I play the game and get to the moment when there is **50 asteroids** (increasing with each level, when you destoy all previous), CPU usage becomes about **20%** 
In addition if I **destroy 49/50 asteroid** and **leave only one** alive, CPU usage will be **still 20%**, though there is nothing to compute ( I mean moving, collssion detection, etc.)

I have the main `GameLoop TimerTask`

```
public void startGameLoop() {
    timer.schedule(gameLoopTask, 0, 17);
    timer.schedule(updateScoreAndLifesTask, 2000, 300); // just update score views
}
class GameLoop extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        game.updateState();
        openGLView.requestRender();
    }
}
public void updateState() {
    ship.move();

    for(int i=0; i<asteroids.size();i++) // asteroids and ship.bullets are ArrayLists
        asteroids.get(i).move();

    for(int i=0; i<ship.bullets.size();i++)
        ship.bullets.get(i).move();

    detectCollision();
}
public void detectCollision() {
    detectCollisionAsteroidsWithBullets();
    if(ship.isAlive && !ship.isImmortal)
        detectCollisionAsteroidsWithShip();     
}
```

And `detectCollision` method loops the copy of `ship.bullets` and `asteroids` `ArrayLists`:

```
public void detectCollisionAsteroidsWithBullets() {
    mainloop: for(int b=0; b < ship.bullets.size(); b++) {  
        for(int a=0; a<asteroids.size(); a++) {
```

and

```
public void detectCollisionAsteroidsWithShip() {        
    mainloop: for(int a=0; a<asteroids.size(); a++) {
        if(isAABBoxIntersectWithAABBox(asteroids.get(a).AABBCoords, ship.AABBCoords)) {
```

So it shouldn't use CPU hard if there is **only 1 asteroid**. Destroying bullets and asteroids = `asteroids.remove(asteroid);` (I just remove it from ArrayList 

So please, help me, I have no idea why it keeps using so much CPU if there is only loops that works prety good with 50 asteroids and for sure shouldn't do 20% CPU usage with only 1 asteroid

Comment: You say you remove destroyed objects. Yet all the code you show uses *clones* of the main list. Most likely you're removing from the wrong list - although this is of course only a guess since the actual code isn't shown.

Comment: @Durandal No, I remove not from clones as I wrote asteroids.remove(asteroid); And If I removed from clones, it would be drawed and I would see it. And clones are cleared always. But thank you anyway.

Comment: EDIT: removed Array cloning, changed it on `for(int a=0; a<asteroids.size(); a++)` PROBLEM IS STILL HERE

Answer (score 0):

Are you supposed to make clones of already existing objects?
The asteroids you destroy will still be there in the game after you destroy them.

You should remove them or start using them again.

Comment: I got a `lAsteroids.clear();` after cycle. And anyway they shouldn't load CPU, they should load RAM but RAM is totaly fine.